# Изменения NS в Cloudflare

Tags: домен, cloudflare, domain, ns

Покупаю домен в Pananames, ставлю туда свои NS, захожу в Cloudflare добавляю туда домен, он просит сменить на NS, который ему нужен. Если снова повторить путь до Cloudflare и поставить заранее те NS, что Cloudflare ранее просил, он пишет, мол поставьте старые NS, что были. Может это связано с местом покупки домена в Pananames? Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: скорее связано с тем, что результаты dns-запросов кэшируются.

Comment: Кэшируются где, вы имеете ввиду на сервере?

Comment: кажется, вы плохо понимаете, что такое [dns](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS).